# rowcolors fill whole row and not just the table row

Tags: latex, tex

Ok so i wrote this simple code (shown below) to create an alternate colour table using \rowcolors, yet instead of just colouring the rows of the table it colours the whole row (even more than textwidth). Any help how to fix this?

```
begin{table}[ht]
\scriptsize
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{white}
\caption{...}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth} | p{0.55\textwidth}}
Filename & Contents \\ 
\hline
\hline
A & B \\
C & F \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `0.45\textwidth` + `0.55\textwidth` would seem to fit within `\textwidth`, each of your `p`-columns have an extra column separation... on *both* sides. To that end, you should remove them in order to make it fit within the text block boundary:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \scriptsize\centering
  \rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{white}
  \caption{This is a table.}
  \begin{tabular}{
      p{\dimexpr0.45\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} | 
      p{\dimexpr0.55\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
    Filename & Contents \\ 
    \hline
    \hline
    A & B \\
    C & F
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Also, [don't use the `center` environment; use `\centering` instead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/5764).

Comment: thank you. the problem was definitely with the size. As I changed it to 0.43 0.53 it worked correctly. I was seeing the problem as it was coming from the \rowcolors and not the matrix itself.